# Combining multiple sheets in excel file to one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, merge

I have a use case where in I have multiple sheets in one excel file [can be any number of files], the columns in each sheets can be any, but I want only "Roll Number", "Brief" from all the sheets combined with each sheet as a column in the new one.

For eg.

If "ClassA" is sheet name and contents are

```
Roll Number    Brief         email
11             Maths 11      abc@abc
11             Science 12    abc@abc
12             History
```

If "ClassB" is the sheet name and contents are

```
Roll Number    Brief         email
11             Art 71        abc@abc
13             Science 12    abc@abc
12             Maths
```

The output I need is

```
Roll Number     ClassA      ClassB
11              Maths 11    Art 71
11              Science 12
12              History     Maths
13              Science 12
```

So I need to merge the df by roll number and want the subsequent "Brief" column informations

tried

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(inputfile)
sheet_names = xls.sheet_names
print(sheet_names)
combined_df = None


for sheet in sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sheet)
    df = df[['Roll Number', 'Brief']]
    df = df.rename(columns={'Brief': sheet})
    if combined_df is None:
        combined_df = df
    else:
        combined_df = pd.merge(combined_df, df, on='Roll Number', how='outer')
print(combined_df)
combined_df.to_excel('combined2.xlsx', index=False)
```

This is creating duplicates or is somewhat irregular for example

```
Roll Number     ClassA      ClassB
11              Maths 11    Art 71
11              Science 12  Art 71
12              History     Maths
13              Science 12
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example Code**

I created a dictionary for your example with sheet_name as the key and dataframe as the value.

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Roll Number': [11, 11, 12], 
         'Brief': ['Maths 11', 'Science 12', 'History'], 
         'email': ['abc@abc', 'abc@abc', None]}
data2 = {'Roll Number': [11, 13, 12], 
         'Brief': ['Art 71', 'Science 12', 'Maths'], 
         'email': ['abc@abc', 'abc@abc', None]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df_dict = {'ClassA': df1, 'ClassB': df2}
```

df_dict:

```
{'ClassA':    Roll Number       Brief    email
 0           11    Maths 11  abc@abc
 1           11  Science 12  abc@abc
 2           12     History     None,
 'ClassB':    Roll Number       Brief    email
 0           11      Art 71  abc@abc
 1           13  Science 12  abc@abc
 2           12       Maths     None}
```

---

**Code**

`df_dict` -> your desired output

i think `concat` is better than `merge` in loop

```
dfs = [
    df[['Roll Number', 'Brief']].assign(cc=df.groupby('Roll Number').cumcount())
    .set_index(['Roll Number', 'cc'])
    .rename({'Brief': sheet}, axis=1)
    for sheet, df in df_dict.items()
]
out = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).droplevel(1).reset_index()
```

out:

```
   Roll Number      ClassA      ClassB
0           11    Maths 11      Art 71
1           11  Science 12         NaN
2           12     History       Maths
3           13         NaN  Science 12
```

now make `df_dict` from your excel file.

```
df_dict = pd.read_excel('your_file_path', sheet_name=None)
```

`sheet_name=None` in `read_excel` make dictionary of sheet name & sheet dataframe in all sheet.

document : [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

---

If the list comprehension in **Code** section is difficult to understand, replace it with a for loop as follows:

```
dfs = []
for sheet, df in df_dict.items():
    df = df[['Roll Number', 'Brief']]
    df['cc'] = df.groupby('Roll Number').cumcount()
    df = df.set_index(['Roll Number', 'cc']).rename({'Brief': sheet}, axis=1)
    dfs.append(df)
    
out = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).droplevel(1).reset_index()
```